# \_tfq_simulate_ops.so not found while import tensorflow_quantum

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-quantum, cirq

Trying import of initial libraries related to tensorflow_quantum:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_quantum as tfq

import cirq
import sympy
import numpy as np
```

```
Getting error in 2nd line:

  File "Path_to_anaconda_site_packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\load_library.py", line 61, in load_op_library
    lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)

NotFoundError: Path_To_Tensorflow_Quantum\core\ops\_tfq_simulate_ops.so not found
```

Comment: import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_quantum as tfq  #error in this line

import cirq
import sympy
import numpy as np

Comment: Is this your full code

Comment: Solution by TFQ team here: https://github.com/tensorflow/quantum/issues/180

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution provided by the Tensorflow team, it worked for me.

```
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.1.0
!pip install cirq==0.7.0 pathos==0.2.5 tensorflow-quantum==0.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Do following steps:

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow
!pip install tensorflow
```

then restart runtime to import the packages.It works.

Comment: Your answer seems to assume that the OP is using Jupyter. I see no indication that this is actually the case. Anyway, `pip --upgrade` would probably make more sense than uninstalling and reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

This might be something that would be worth raising as an issue on the TensorFlow Quantum Github here (https://github.com/tensorflow/quantum/issues). Without much information on the platform your are using or even what python version you have it might be hard to diagnose the problem here, but a quick fix you could try might be that you have an older version of TensorFlow installed. TensorFlow Quantum requires tf == 2.1.0.

```sh
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

If that doesn't do it, then it might be worth opening an issue on github and giving a few more details on there :)